# calculate cosine similarity in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I have a candidate document embedding tensor, namely `cdd_doc_embeddings` of size `[batch_size, cdd_size, signal_length, embedding_dim]`, a history clicked document embedding tensor, namely `his_doc_embeddings` of size `[batch_size, his_size, signal_length, embedding_dim]`.

Now I want to compute the `cosine similarity` between them, yielding a tensor `fusion_matrix` of size `[batch_size, cdd_size, his_size, signal_length, signal_length]` where **entry [ b,i,j,u,v ] denotes the cosine similarity between the *u* th word in *i* th candidate document in *b* th batch and the *v* th word in *j* th history clicked document in *b* th batch**.

How can I do it efficiently with **`PyTorch`**?

Comment: there is a pytorch function for calculating the cosine similarity [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CosineSimilarity.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured it out.

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
# [bs, cs, 1, sl, ed]
cdd_news_embedding = F.normalize(self.embedding[cdd_news_batch].unsqueeze(dim=2), dim=-1)
# [bs, 1, hs, ed, sl]
his_news_embedding = F.normalize(self.embedding[his_news_batch].unsqueeze(dim=1), dim=-1).transpose(-1,-2)

# transform cosine similarity calculation into normalized matrix production
fusion_matrices = torch.matmul(cdd_news_embedding, his_news_embedding).unsqueeze(dim=-1)
```